# Design pattern to process events

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to understand the most suitable (Java) design pattern to use to process a series of messages.  Each message includes a "type" which determines how the data contained in the message should be processed.

I have been considering the Command pattern, but are struggling to understand the roles/relevance of the specific Command classes.  So far, I have determined that the receiver will contain the code that implements the message processing methods.  Concrete commands would be instantiated based on message type.  However, I have no idea how the actual message data should be passed.  Should it be passed to the receiver constructor with the appropriate receiver methods being called by the concrete command execute method?  Maybe the message data should be passed in the receiver action method invocations?

I am fairly new to all of this so any guidance would be appreciated.

This may help:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute(String msg);
}

public class AO1Command implements Command {

    Receiver rec = new Receiver();

    public void execute(String msg) {
        rec.admit(msg);
    }
}

public class CommandFactory {

    public protected CommandFactory () { }

    public static Command getInstance(String type)  {

       if (type.equals("A01")) return new A01Command();
       else if (type.equals("A02")) return new A02Command();
       else {
          return null; 
       }
}
```

Comment: Just a little side note. Never use the operator for equality (==) to compare strings. Depending on the jvm implementation "hello"=="hello" might evaluate to false. This is because == operator uses object identity meaning that it is only true if both objects are identical. "hello" == "hello" might actually construct two string objects -> not identical. Use equals() method instead

Comment: @bennidi: Thank you for this.  I have edited the example - and checked the original code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, your title says a pattern for handling events.  If you are talking about an actual event framework, then the Observer/Observable pattern comes to mind.  This would work when you want do fire an event of some type, then have event handlers pick up the processing of the events.

Seems like your problem is in the implementation details of the command pattern.  Can you post some code that shows where you are stuck?

Note that patterns are not mutually exclusive, you could use the command pattern in the context of the Observable pattern.

EDIT -- based on your code, you should

1) make the `CommandFactory` static.
2) pass the type to the `getCommand` method, which should also be static.
3) You don't need reflection for this, you can simply do

```
if (type == "type1") return new Command1();
else if (type == "type2") return new Command2();
...
```

Im not saying you can't use reflection, I'm saying its overcomplicating what you are trying to do.  Plus, they way you are doing it binds the the String that represents the message type to the implementation details of the command class names, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Can you expand on this? An observer could be used to gather messages to be processed, e.g. if they are generated by clicking on Swing GUI components, but the Command pattern seems more relevant to actually processing the messages.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  I have been working through this further - to explain the messages that I am dealing with are HL7 (Health language 7).  Not that that matters but the structures are similar - only the required actions are different.  So an A01 is an "patient admit" and and A02 is a "patient transfer".  The key is that each message has a type (A01, A02 etc).  So workign through the advice:

Comment: @user808655 where are you stuck?

Comment: I have changed the code a bit for to make the CommandFactory method static as per hvgotcodes advice and added what I think must be the receiver (a bit like a DAO?).  I think that the issue that is troubling me now is that I need to create some sort of XM reader to extract the "type" for the command factory.  However, I also need to create an XML reader to manipulate the data in the receiver.  This seems unnecessary duplication - I am not sure how to use one instance of an XM Reader and be consistent with the Command pattern.  I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. A Command pattern is the appropriate solution to the outlined problem.

To answer your question, you would have your CommandFactory instantiate an appropriate Command instance based on the data differentiator (in this case some data in your message). You would then invoke a method on the Command instance, passing in your message. It is common (best) practice to call this method Execute(...), but you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: I have tried to do this with the example code I loaded above.  In some of the examples I have looked at the actual code that implements commands is encapsulated in Command receiver methods so that the command execute method just calls say receiver.admit().  This would mean (I think) that the message woudl be held by the receiver rather than the command?  Apologies if I am confusing things here....

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look to the Jakarta Digester project (to process XML), it has a SAX implementation, wich is an event based API as explained here http://www.saxproject.org/event.html, it's a short explanation but could serve as a starting point for you.